# On down arrow key cursor going inside a div containing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-editor

I am modifying bootstrap based HTML editor. I have done image uploading part.In image uploading, I am creating an image inside a div.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid;padding: 10px; width: 300px;resize: both;overflow: auto;">
    <img src="uploads/images/dark_knight.jpg"> 
</div>
```

I want image to be resizeable hence,

```
element.style {
   border: 1px solid;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 300px;
   resize: both;
   overflow: auto;
  }
```

But the issue is when I am hitting a down key cursor is going inside a div containing an image (instead of below a div).

so what changes should I do in order to bring cursor below a div on pressing key down?

Comment: Can you include more code, a working representation of the current state of your project? a JSFiddle would be nice.
Also, I'm not clear on what it is exactly that you need. Do I understand correctly:
1) You're talking about an editor where the user can place an image inside a <div>.
2) when the input cursor (focus) is above the div, and the user presses the down arrow, you want it to skip below the div instead of inside
?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/govi20/u37cxxbh/    here jsfiddle for you. sorry for bad formatting ,it's code generated by bootstrap based HTML editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/u37cxxbh/2/

Make div `contenteditable="false"` and add `textarea` element next to image. As in example above.

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding

```
contenteditable="false"
```

to the div containing the image seems to solve the problem.

```css
#editor {
  overflow: scroll;
  max-height: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: white;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
  padding: 4px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 1px 1px 0px inset;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 1px 1px 0px inset;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  overflow: scroll;
  outline: none;
}
div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">First line
  <div>
    //after clicking down arrow key cursor going inside an image div

    <div style="border: 1px solid;padding: 10px; width: 300px;resize: both;overflow: auto;" contenteditable="false">
      <img src="abcd.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div>Last line</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wont that make everything ineditable and Not fix the cursor going outside of inner div problem alone